# What GPO's use REG_BINARY values

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry, gpo

Does anyone know off-hand any Windows 7 local computer (prefer computer but I can use a user) GPO entries that store their values in as a REG_BINARY type value?

I'm trying to validate some custom code for modifying the Registry.pol file for some special MDT/SCCM OS deployment tasks sequences.

Finding SZ, DWORD, QWORD, even MULTI_SZ was pretty easy but I need a GPO setting that uses REG_BINARY type to load and save to ensure my logic isn't jacking up the byte order going from in memory to saved file.